# PHP codeigniter-> Images not showing from root folder

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, localhost, wamp

I've searched the answer for this issue but it seems that my images won't show on the admin view.

i have my images in the root folder of localhost

and it shows me this error in the web console.

```
 GET http://localhost/tarea8/fotos/8.png 404 (Not Found)
 GET http://localhost/tarea8/fotos/9.png 404 (Not Found)
```

here is my code to fetch the images

```
<?php
    $imagenes = cargar_imagenes();
    //$route = base_url('fotos');

    foreach($imagenes as $imagen){
      echo "<tr>"?>
      <td><img src="<?php echo base_url('/fotos')?>/<?php echo $imagen->id?>.png" height='50' class="img-thumbnail"></td>
      <?php
      echo
      "<td>{$imagen->id}</td>
      <td>{$imagen->nombre}</td>
      <td>{$imagen->comentario}</td>

      <tr>";
    }
     ?>
```

where cargar_imagenes is my method to call the database and call my images assigned via id, everything fetches well but for some reason images won't show.

hope somebody can help.

Comment: Try with out forward slash in `base_url('fotos')` make sure baseurl is set in config.php

Comment: try to add the semi colon ` echo "<tr>"; ?>` and at the end of your `echo` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
  <td><img src="<?php echo base_url('fotos/'.$imagen->id); ?>" height='50' class="img-thumbnail"></td>
```

Comment: thanks seems like i've changed some configuration access in my .htaccess and then it accepted the route as you wrote it and it showed the image.

Answer (score 0):

You save image extension in database if yes then remove .png after image code